# Объединение int со строкой в си

Tags: c, char, fopen

Необходимо реализовать работу следующей функции fopen(“name”+i+”.txt”,”w”), где i является переменной int, вопрос как это сделать, функцией itoa() не вышло. Так же не должно быть функции связанной со string (пишу на чистом си), только массив char.

Comment: Приведите ваш код и возникающие ошибки

Comment: sprintf в помощь

Comment: или strcat с itoa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```c
char buffer[100];

sprintf(buffer, "name%d.txt", 14);

printf("%s", buffer); // name14.txt
```

Comment: 10 - не маловато будет для int? `char buffer[N];` резервирует место под `'\0'`?

Comment: @vp_arth, окей, поправил)

Comment: 100 - не многовато будет для int? ;)

Comment: @wololo много не мало :)

Comment: Если сильно мучают сомнения с длиной буфера, то вызывайте [asprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)

Comment: Или `snprintf`: если передать ей 0 вторым аргументом, она вернёт необходимый размер буфера.

Answer (score 2):

```
char name[50];
sprintf(name,"name%d.txt",i);
fopen(name,"w");
```